# jQuery scroll down function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
      }, 500, 'linear');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollDown">
  <a href="#nextSection"><span></span>toliau</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You get that error because the `#nextSection` element doesn't exist, hence `offset()` is undefined, and trying to access a property of an undefined object gets you the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Just change this line i hope it will work

```
 scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
```

To this

```
  scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
      }, 500, 'linear');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollDown">
  <a href="#nextSection"><span></span>toliau</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Copied my answer what is the change

Comment: The difference between our answers is you have given change while i have given working output and if you believe that answer#copied than you can check my past answers i have given many answers on offset. BTW thank you for your down vote :-)